# Bash retain leading zero in front of Decimal Number Format

Tags: bash, decimal, octal

I have a script that collects list of files based on time given by user in GMT. For example, [from: 0900 to: 1200]. The problem is that first I convert user entered number (which is octal) to decimal. Upon doing that, the zeroes in front gets truncated. Below is my code.

```
from1="0900"
from=$((10#$from1)); #Converting from Octal to Decimal
to1="1200"
to=$((10#$to1)); #Converting from Octal to Decimal
```

The output of from: `900`

This is where the problem arises because I need leading zero in front in order to output the values between `from` and `to`

```
if [[ $from -le $val && $val -le $to ]]
then
     echo $val >> some_output.txt
fi
```

This above snippet does NOT get triggered because value of from is `900` and not `0900`.

How can I address this? Is there a way to add leading zero in front while comparing inside the if statement?

Thank you.

Comment: `from=$((10#$from1));`, this doesn't convert anything from octal, it just forces the number to be interpreted as decimal. Besides, `0900` isn't even a valid octal number. And, your users enter numbers in octal? That sounds rather quaint. What is it you're actually doing?

Comment: @ilkkachu the leading zero in front is what makes it interpreted as octal. The User enters `from` and `to` values. For simplicity, I just assigned some values in above example. Shown in my if statement above, I want it to take times that falls between `from` and `to` and append it to output file. For example if file contains `[0850, 0910, 0950, 1020, 1040, 1100, 1300, 1500] ` it should add `0910, 0950, 1020, 1040, 1100` to the output file. As of right now I cannot do that because value of from is not interpreted properly.

Comment: is there a reason why you're converting the strings to numbers? any reason why you don't just compare the strings, eg, `[[ ! "${from1}" > "${val}" && ! "${val}" > "${to1}" ]]`; alternatively, keep your strings and numbers, do your comparisons w/ numbers but then use the strings for follow-on processing ... ?

Comment: @markp-fuso, I think that would break if they give `900` instead of `0900`.

Comment: @ilkkachu ... sure, so OP would want to add some additional code to make sure all values are left-padded with `0`, along with additional checks that the numbers represent actual times (ie, '978` would be invalid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to treat the numbers as decimal, regardless of the leading zero, you can add the `10#` prefix in Bash (if you had negative numbers, it would need to be after the minus sign).

This prints

```
901 is between 0900 and 1200
1101 is between 0900 and 1200
```

```
#!/bin/bash
between() {
        local val=$1
        local from=$2
        local to=$3
        if [[ "10#$from" -le "10#$val" ]] && [[ "10#$val" -le "10#$to" ]]; then
                echo "$val is between $from and $to"
                return 0
        fi
        return 1
}

between  901 0900 1200
between  809 0900 1200
between 0809 0900 1200
between 1101 0900 1200
between 1300 0900 1200
```

Alternatively, you could remove the leading zeroes, or pad the numbers to an equal length and compare as strings.